# CStringA::ReverseFind doesn't work as expected when compiled as 64 bit code

Tags: c++, mfc

This simple code asserts (see comment in the code) when the code is compiled as 64 bit. When compiled as 32 bit it doesn't assert.

Actually the problem occurs when `CStringA::ReverseFind` is used to find a character whose most significant bit is  1.

The code below illustrates the problem: searching for `|` works, but searching for `¦` fails.

Strangely only `CStringA::ReverseFind` has this problem, `CStringA::Find` works fine.

Other information:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2022 17.8.0
- Platform Toolset Visual Studio 2022 (v143)
- Windows SDK 10.0.22621.0

```
#include <afxwin.h>

void TEST()
{
  CStringW st0w(L"AB¦CD");
  CStringA st0a("AB¦CD");
  CStringW st1w(L"AB|CD");
  CStringA st1a("AB|CD");

  ASSERT(st1w.Find(L'|') == 2);
  ASSERT(st1a.Find('|') == 2);
  ASSERT(st0w.Find(L'¦') == 2);
  ASSERT(st0a.Find('¦') == 2);

  ASSERT(st1w.ReverseFind(L'|') == 2);
  ASSERT(st1a.ReverseFind('|') == 2);
  ASSERT(st0w.ReverseFind(L'¦') == 2);
  ASSERT(st0a.ReverseFind('¦') == 2);  // code asserts here
}

int main()
{
   TEST();
}
```

Is this a bug in MFC?

Has someone encountered this before?

Comment: *The Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) Library supplies full source code. Header files (.h) are in the \atlmfc\include directory. Implementation files (.cpp) are in the \atlmfc\src\mfc directory.* Why not look at the code and self-answer your question?

Comment: @273K I know, but this bug is so obvious, I hoped that someone might have encountered this before. And yes I have already had a look at the source code, but it's heavily templated code that is all but easy to read.

Comment: What does [`IsDBCSLeadByte()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-isdbcsleadbyte) return for `'¦'` on your system?

Comment: It can be signed `char` to unsigned `wchar_t` conversion issue.

Comment: @IInspectable `IsDBCSLeadByte((BYTE)'¦')` returns 0. But anyway it's the CString**A** version that has the problem

Comment: @273K Yes, signed char to unsigned wchar_tconversion is definitely a suspect here, but then it should be the same with 32 bit and 64 bit code.

Comment: No, different CRT are linked.

Comment: If you're trying to navigate "code" and find yourself drowning in Template Soup, make sure you give [Template IntelliSense](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/template-intellisense/) a try. I still find it curious that the behavior changes between target *architectures*.

Comment: @273K yes, of course it's not the same code, one is 32 bit code the other 64 bit code, but the behaviour should be the same otherwise it's a bug in the library IMO.

Comment: The arg must be `wchar_t`, you pass `char`. What bug in CRT are you taking about? This is a bug in your code.

Comment: @273K [`CStringT::ReverseFind()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#reversefind) takes an argument of type `XCHAR`. That's a [type alias for](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt-predefined-types): *"A single character (either `wchar_t` or `char`) with the same character type as the `CStringT` object."* In other words: When you're calling `ReverseFind()` on a `CStringA`, that argument must be of type `char`. I cannot see an issue with the code here.

Comment: the issue you describe sounds a lot like the (decennia old) bug that Stephan T. Lavawey discovered a few years ago in microsofts implementation of memcmp or strcmp in its standard library.there was a conversion error regarding the high-order bit.

Comment: "either" != "any".

Comment: @engf-010 Did STL publish information on this? A video, blog post, or a scientific paper disguised as a commit message?

Comment: @IInspectable: Yes, there is a youtube video in which he  explains it. Sorry ,I don't recall which one ,it's been a few years (more than 3 less than 5 ,I think).

Comment: @Iinspectable:  It was actually a bit earlier (7 years) :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXH18n_IVac&list=PLnE6dhNYoLZ6Y8k8l4fRz3lk-K6fAp5-K&index=8

Comment: @273K  Still, if there is a bug in _my_ code, then why does `Find` yield 2 but `ReverseFind` yields -1? Both `Find` and `ReverseFind` should return the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug, though not in MFC but in the underlying standard library implementation, specifically `strrchr` function.

Here's my non-MFC repro, still asserts as commented for x64:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct alignas(32) {
    char pad[8];
    wchar_t val[8] = L"AB¦CD";
} st0w;

struct alignas(32) {
    char pad[8];
    char val[8] = "AB¦CD";
} st0a;

struct alignas(32) {
    char pad[8];
    wchar_t val[8] = L"AB|CD";
} st1w;

struct alignas(32) {
    char pad[8];
    char val[8] = "AB|CD";
} st1a;

void test1()
{
    assert(wcschr(st1w.val, L'|') == st1w.val + 2);
    assert(strchr(st1a.val, (unsigned char)'|')  == st1a.val + 2);
    assert(wcschr(st0w.val, L'¦') == st0w.val + 2);
    assert(strchr(st0a.val, (unsigned char)'¦')  == st0a.val + 2);

assert(wcsrchr(st1w.val, L'|') == st1w.val + 2);
    assert(strrchr(st1a.val, (unsigned char)'|')  == st1a.val + 2);
    assert(wcsrchr(st0w.val, L'¦') == st0w.val + 2);
    assert(strrchr(st0a.val, (unsigned char)'¦')  == st0a.val + 2);  // code asserts here
}

int main()
{
    test1();
}
```

I observe that there's a vectorized implementation of `strrchr` function is seen in the debugger. It does unaligned part unvectorized, then something fancy vectorized.

The difference between x64 and x86 is explained by that they do not share the implementation. x86 version is implemented in Assembler, not in C or C++.

The `alignas(32)` and `char pad[8]` it to make sure the string is not aligned to vectorization natural boundary.

I've created a bug report: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/strrchr-doesnt-work-as-expected-for-x64/10610842

The problem I think is that `strrchr` makes sign extension of the source characters to `int` and compares integers. Using `strrchr(st0a.GetString(), (signed char)'¦')` should avoid the issue. MFC has `(unsigned char)` cast inside, so the comparand is zero extended. The difference between `'¦'` and `'|'` is that `'¦'` is above 0x7F, so sign extension and zero extension produce different results.

Comment: That is very helpful.  In the meantime I've circumvented the bug (that is I don't use `CString::ReverseFind` anymore but I call a replacement function I wrote on my own (not very elegant, but it does the job and I didn't have many occurrences of `ReverseFind` in my project.)

Comment: @Jabberwocky, think you can go with `strrchr(st0a.GetString(), (signed char)'¦')`, I've expanded my answer (and removed the part about alignment, as now I see why it is this way)